# Gluon Mobile with JavaFX 20 does not allow to write to text fields

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

Using the following versions

```
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.11.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.18</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

        <java-version>17</java-version>
        <javafx-version>20</javafx-version>

        <charm-version>6.2.3</charm-version>
        <attach-version>4.0.19-SNAPSHOT</attach-version>
```

with
`<javafxStaticSdkVersion>20</javafxStaticSdkVersion>` and graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final.

If I have a text field, clicking on it to edit it does nothing. If I switch to `<javafx-version>19</javafx-version>` and `<javafxStaticSdkVersion>19</javafxStaticSdkVersion>`, editing works as it should (the caret is shown and the keyboard comes up).

Tested on Galaxy S7 with Android 8.

Is there a bug with JavaFX 20?

---

Edit: with JavaFX 21-ea+17 I get a black screen on startup

```
05-19 18:18:30.431 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled: Exception in Application start method
05-19 18:18:30.437 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.javafx.font.FontConfigManager.getFontConfig(Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/sun/javafx/font/FontConfigManager$FcCompFont;Z)Z [symbol: Java_com_sun_javafx_font_FontConfigManager_getFontConfig or Java_com_sun_javafx_font_FontConfigManager_getFontConfig__Ljava_lang_String_2_3Lcom_sun_javafx_font_FontConfigManager_00024FcCompFont_2Z]
05-19 18:18:30.437 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNINativeLinkage.getOrFindEntryPoint(JNINativeLinkage.java:153)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.nativeCallAddress(JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.java:52)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.FontConfigManager.getFontConfig(FontConfigManager.java)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.FontConfigManager.initFontConfigLogFonts(FontConfigManager.java:159)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.FontConfigManager.getFontConfigFont(FontConfigManager.java:268)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.freetype.FTFactory.getFallbacks(FTFactory.java:134)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getLinkedFonts(LogicalFont.java:214)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getNumSlots(LogicalFont.java:223)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.<init>(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:62)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.LogicalFont.getGlyphMapper(LogicalFont.java:439)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:229)
05-19 18:18:30.438 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:800)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1051)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:230)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:256)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:432)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.text.Text.doComputeLayoutBounds(Text.java:1138)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.text.Text$1.doComputeLayoutBounds(Text.java:143)05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.TextHelper.computeLayoutBoundsImpl(TextHelper.java:95)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.computeLayoutBounds(NodeHelper.java:108)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node$13.computeBounds(Node.java:3474)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9799)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9790)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression.getValue(ObjectExpression.java:49)
05-19 18:18:30.439 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.addListener(ExpressionHelper.java:64)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.addListener(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:54)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:285)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.<init>(LabeledSkinBase.java:160)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.<init>(LabelSkin.java:52)05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.Label.createDefaultSkin(Label.java:161)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:910)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:88)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:68)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9605)
05-19 18:18:30.440 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9598)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9598)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:587)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2595)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:401)05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:169)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:400)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:430)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:592)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:572)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:565)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:352)
05-19 18:18:30.441 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
05-19 18:18:30.442 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
05-19 18:18:30.442 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
05-19 18:18:30.442 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:704)
05-19 18:18:30.442 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:202)
05-19 18:18:30.443 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled: QuantumRenderer: shutdown
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:447)
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.isNestedLoopRunning(Application.java:548)
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.isNestedLoopRunning(QuantumToolkit.java:1217)
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:652)
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.application.Platform.enterNestedEventLoop(Platform.java:307)
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.lambda$installIntoMobileApplication$7(Dialog.java:605)
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:192)
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:91)
05-19 18:18:30.444 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:104)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:101)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(BooleanPropertyBase.java:239)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:91)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:104)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:79)
05-19 18:18:30.445 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer.show(Layer.java:289)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:556)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.NagScreenPresenter.lambda$showDialog$1(NagScreenPresenter.java:77)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:169)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
05-19 18:18:30.446 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:704)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:202)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:704)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:202)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.javafx.font.FontConfigManager.getFontConfig(Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/sun/javafx/font/FontConfigManager$FcCompFont;Z)Z [symbol: Java_com_sun_javafx_font_FontConfigManager_getFontConfig or Java_com_sun_javafx_font_FontConfigManager_getFontConfig__Ljava_lang_String_2_3Lcom_sun_javafx_font_FontConfigManager_00024FcCompFont_2Z]
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNINativeLinkage.getOrFindEntryPoint(JNINativeLinkage.java:153)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.nativeCallAddress(JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.java:52)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.FontConfigManager.getFontConfig(FontConfigManager.java)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.FontConfigManager.initFontConfigLogFonts(FontConfigManager.java:159)
05-19 18:18:30.447 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.FontConfigManager.getFontConfigFont(FontConfigManager.java:268)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.freetype.FTFactory.getFallbacks(FTFactory.java:134)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.FallbackResource.getLinkedFonts(FallbackResource.java:287)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.FallbackResource.getNumSlots(FallbackResource.java:296)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismCompositeFontResource.getNumSlots(PrismCompositeFontResource.java:61)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.<init>(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:62)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismCompositeFontResource.getGlyphMapper(PrismCompositeFontResource.java:160)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:229)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:800)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1051)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:230)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:256)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.Utils.computeTextWidth(Utils.java:129)
05-19 18:18:30.448 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.skin.ProgressIndicatorSkin$DeterminateIndicator.lambda$new$0(ProgressIndicatorSkin.java:518)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.lambda$new$1(LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:88)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:86)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:192)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:91)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:106)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:113)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:82)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.applyStyle(StyleableObjectProperty.java:68)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.transitionToState(CssStyleHelper.java:954)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node.doProcessCSS(Node.java:9723)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node$1.doProcessCSS(Node.java:481)
05-19 18:18:30.449 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSSImpl(NodeHelper.java:194)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1401)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1401)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
05-19 18:18:30.450 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:913)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:88)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:68)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1401)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1401)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1401)
05-19 18:18:30.451 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1401)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9605)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:587)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1786)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:411)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:65)
05-19 18:18:30.452 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1163)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1239)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1254)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:277)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.continueInit(AppManager.java:334)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.start(AppManager.java:288)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.demo.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:42)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:169)
05-19 18:18:30.453 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
05-19 18:18:30.454 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
05-19 18:18:30.454 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
05-19 18:18:30.454 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
05-19 18:18:30.454 17837 17855 D GraalCompiled:         ... 3 more
```

Comment: Yes, [JDK-8304476](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8304476). This [PR](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/pull/1110) should fix it, but in the meantime you need to use 21-ea+5 or 21+ea+17 for the static SDK.

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried using 21-ea+17 for both the JavaFX dependency and the static SDK. I got the exception above on launching the app.

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing class to the `jniConfig` list, or if you run the native agent, the missing class/method to the jni file?

Comment: @JoséPereda `FontConfigManager` is not a class that I use directly. The same code works with JavaFX 19. If something changed in 21 then I would say it should be fixed at the tool level.

Comment: Yes, but that fix will simply add the missing configuration to the jni config file provided by Substrate. In the meantime, you can try it yourself.